# making vars for elements not yet created

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a var for a dom element to clean things up but it doesn't give me expected results. The reason I think it's doing this is because the element isn't yet created when I run the function. I could move the var after the .prepend() is called but what if I'd like to keep all my vars at the top?

Would adding .on() somewhere in this script fix my problem or should I just move the var down a few lines after .prepend is run, and forget about keeping vars up top?

```
    (function () {
        var cp = $(".call-out p")

        $('li').eq(2).prepend('hi');
        $('div.call-out').prepend("<p>MY UL</p>");
        cp.css({
             'font-size': '3em',
             'background': 'orange'
        });
        cp.animate({
              width: "1000px",
              height: "1250px"
        });
        cp.click(function (e) {
             $(this).animate({
              width: "125px",
              height: "90px"
       });
     });
   })();
```

Comment: Now, I know that it's 'good style' to keep your variables cropped together at the top of a block, but nobody ever said anything about actually initializing them there, right? That means: Keep your variable names up top, but fill them only after the actual element has been created. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jQuery object can be constructed from html so you can do it this way:

```
var cp = $("<p>MY UL</p>").css({....});/* can add css or event handlers before insert into DOM*/

$('li').eq(2).prepend('hi');
$('div.call-out').prepend(cp);
 /* although created outside the DOM, once inserted the object still exists to use jQuery methods on*/
 cp.animate({....});
```

Methods like `html()` and `prepend()` amongst others will accept a multiple types as content arguments including a jQuery object

Look closely at the `content` definition for `prepend()` in API docs:  http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: This would be a great workaround but I am trying to learn about structure and how its a best practice to turn a dom traversal into a var so you are not continuously calling it. So instead of calling $(".call-out p") everytime and accessing the dom I can store in a var and just use cp

Comment: your concept is the same thing. Have to understand that no matter how it gets referenced, it is still a unique jQuery object. Wait..might be an issue if there are more than one `.call-out` . If not...the 2 methods arrive at same result

Comment: see this demo . If you have multiple elements that are getting prepended..the prepend will work as I outlined, but the `cp` won't be a collection http://jsfiddle.net/bYZ3b/ If you need a collection you will have to prepend first, then create the collection. There are other ways but with more code and not going to complicate this with them

Comment: a far as best practice... you still have to work within the flow of the code processes, so creating everything in one place first isn't always practical or possible